# Woocommerce Create product automatically when other product gets out of stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to buil a woocommerce website. I only need a product at a time, but i need to automatically create another product when the first one stays out of stock.

I have this code to create the product from php

```
$post = array(
     'post_author' => $user_id,
     'post_content' => '',
     'post_status' => "publish",
     'post_title' => $product->part_num,
     'post_parent' => '',
     'post_type' => "product",

     );
      //Create post
     $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
     if($post_id){
     $attach_id = get_post_meta($product->parent_id, "_thumbnail_id", true);
     add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
    }
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Races', 'product_cat' );
     wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');



     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
     update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0');
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'yes');
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes');
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', "1" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', "1" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_purchase_note', "" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', "no" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', "" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_length', "" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_width', "" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_height', "" );
     update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', "");
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', array());
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', "" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', "" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', "1" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sold_individually', "" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manage_stock', "no" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_backorders', "no" );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', "" );

     // file paths will be stored in an array keyed off md5(file path)
    $downdloadArray =array('name'=>"Test", 'file' => $uploadDIR['baseurl']."/video/".$video);

    $file_path =md5($uploadDIR['baseurl']."/video/".$video);


    $_file_paths[  $file_path  ] = $downdloadArray;
    // grant permission to any newly added files on any existing orders for this product
    //do_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_file_download_paths', $post_id, 0, $downdloadArray );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable_files ', $_file_paths);
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_download_limit', '');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_download_expiry', '');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_download_type', '');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_image_gallery', '');
```

So, how can i trigger this php file so when the first product stays out of stock, it creates automatically a new one?

Comment: Perhaps one of these hooks: [`woocommerce_product_on_backorder`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L2509) or if you have no stock notifications enabled then [`woocommerce_no_stock`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L2516).

Comment: How I can add product featured product when I don't know `parent_id`